# Поиск повторений через map

Tags: c++, vector, map

Решал задачу, суть которой было найти максимальное количество повторений. После решения задачи посмотрел предложенный вариант её решения. В итоге функция возврата максимального значения имела вид

```
int FindMaxRepetitionCount(const vector<Region>& regions) {
  int result = 0;
  map<Region, int> repetion_count;
  for (const Region& region : regions) {
    result = max(result, ++repetion_count[region]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Меня интересует вопрос связанный с начальным значением переменной типа int. Неужели для словаря, если я не определяю переменную, то она по умолчанию 0? И для других типов данных будет аналогично?

Comment: да, по умолчанию  отоброжаемый обьект инициализируется значением по умолчанию.  Этот факт используется часто

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan , Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы не определяете переменную, то никакой переменной и нет. А если вы не инициализируете переменную типа `int` (ровно как и прочих встроенных типов), то она будет содержать мусор и любая попытка использовать хранящееся значение приводит к неопределенному поведению. Из этого правила есть исключение - статические переменные могут неявно инициализироваться нулями.