# Найти количество дубликатов в std::map

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl, map

Как найти количество дубликатов в `map`?

```
std::map<int, int> coor;
coor.emplace(0xafedcab8, 428);
coor.emplace(0xafedcc65, 82);
coor.emplace(0xafedccc0, 136);
coor.emplace(0xafedcf47, 82);
coor.emplace(0xafedd185, 136);
coor.emplace(0xafedd26a, 82);
```

как сделать так?

```
число 82    3 раза
число 136   2 раза
число 428   1 раза
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: мне нужно вывести сколько раз в массиве встречается эллемент

Comment: Это понятно, но вы сами пробовали сделать что-то, попробуйте прочитать документацию.

Comment: [В предыдущем вопросе же решение есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884174/Поиск-повторений-через-map)

Comment: да пробовал, если бы у меня небыло проблемм я бы не спрашивал

Comment: VTT там ищут повторы в веторе мне нужно найти в мапе

Comment: Решение однако то же самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, простейший способ -

```
std::map<int, int> multi;
for(auto& p: coor)
    multi[p.second]++;
for(auto& p: multi)
    cout << "Число " << p.first << "   "
        << p.second << " раза.\n";
```

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста, а как отсортировать теперь по колличеству раз?

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович Например, еще раз развернуть и положить в очередной `map`... :)